# Docker - is not running

Tags: laravel, docker

I want to install laravel8 with  curl -s https://laravel.build/example-app | bash ,get this error:

> "docker is not running "

Comment: Do you think it's running? What steps have you taken to debug this?

Comment: please provider more details so we can help you

Comment: thanks for your attention , i resolved this error with this command and add sudo before bash , curl -s https://laravel.build/example-app | sudo bash  !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@sheydan you should install docker before launch command-line.
If you don't know how to use DOCKER. Refer to documentation of Laravel https://laravel.com/docs/8.x there is lot of method instead of docker.

Comment: thanks for your attention , i resolved this error with this command and add sudo before bash , curl -s https://laravel.build/example-app | sudo bash  !!!

Answer (score 7):

Please try sudo; it worked for me.

`curl -s https://laravel.build/meta-app | sudo bash`

Comment: Thank you, my app is working now.

Answer (score 4):

Adding to the other answers, If you already have WSL Linux & Docker installed.

In Docker Desktop's settings make sure your distro has been allowed access:
[image]

Then, You have to make sure your user can access docker (By default it's restricted to root/sudo)

Inside WSL:

```bash
$ sudo groupadd docker
$ sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```

Will create & Add you to the "docker" group, which is required to run docker without sudo.

source: https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/#manage-docker-as-a-non-root-user

Answer (score 3):

While running docker on a Ubuntu desktop i got the same error while following the tutorial to install Laravel:

```
sudo chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock
```

fixed it for me

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who  faces the same issue.

First you need to download and install a Linux distribution Ubuntu worked for me.
Then you need to install it.
Verify that it's installed and running.

Run the command `wsl --list --version`. Make sure that the version that Ubuntu is version 2.

If not then you need to change it to version 2.
Open Docker >settings > resources > WSL integration activate Ubuntu distribution apply and restart.

Run `wsl --list --verbose`. Set the default distribution to ubuntu.

Then run the curl from laravel page.

That worked for me. #

Answer (score 0):

I had to run this in my Ubuntu `WSL` terminal : export `DOCKER_HOST=tcp://localhost:2375`

and it finally installed for me.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34830386)